# Drupal retrieve first name instead of name/realname?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How can I retrieve the first name instead of name (raw username) or realname, so I can use it in an email template variable !username?

```
$variables['!username'] = $params['account']->realname;
```

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/faq_ask/tree/faq_ask.module?id=be753ca5c5fe51f33c0515999ceb3a4179298da8#n1052

Not sure if that relates to realname or perhaps where 'account' is defined to something...?

I created a **field for first name** that gets pulled by LDAP to provide for realname and have the **token [user:field-first-name]**.

Can I pull this from the token somehow?

**Update - code where user load is used:**

```
$account = user_load($expert->uid);
        $params = array(
          'category' => is_object($term)?$term->tid:-1,
          'question' => $node->title,
          'question_details' => $node->detailed_question,
          'nid' => $node->nid,
          'creator' => theme('username', array('account' => user_load($node->uid), 'plain' => TRUE)),
          'account' => $account,
        );
```

I tried

```
$account = user_load($expert->uid);
$first_name = $account->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
        $params = array(
          'category' => is_object($term)?$term->tid:-1,
          'question' => $node->title,
          'question_details' => $node->detailed_question,
          'nid' => $node->nid,
          'creator' => theme('username', array('account' => user_load($node->uid), 'plain' => TRUE)),
          'account' => $first_name,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created a custom field for the first name and want to access it using the user email, you can do it like this:

```
$user = user_load_by_mail($mail); 
$first_name = $user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

Comment: Many Thanks Daniela for your help! 
I tried but couldn't make it work yet. I updated code above, where I noticed it's using **user_load** instead. Could I utilise this too or would it only work with **user_load_by_mail** 

see http://cgit.drupalcode.org/faq_ask/tree/faq_ask.module?id=be753ca5c5fe51f33c0515999ceb3a4179298da8#n475

Comment: The code also works with user_load($user->uid); . So, debug your code and make sure that $expert variable contains the user objetc.

Comment: great thanks, I just found out i can look into the available fields using dpm **"dpm($account) "** :) which confirmed the field is there :)

I managed to make it work by simply adding the "->field_first_name['und'][0]['value']" which now I learned pulls in the field object into the variable, cool thanks again.